# Regex - Get string between quotes even if it's empty

Tags: regex

To get `"Testing if \"quotes\" are working."` from this string:
`msgid "Testing if \"quotes\" are working."`,
I am using this pattern:

```
~msgid(?:\s*)(\"[^\"](?:\\.|[^\"])*\")~m
```

However, it fails if I have `msgid ""`

How can I extract string even if it's empty?

Comment: Isn't the piece `[^\"]` asking for a character that is not double-quote `"`? This is what doesn't let you extract empty string, I think. "What is the applicable programming language?" would be a thing to add to the question too.

Comment: You are awesome. Please post answer so I can accept it - it works!

Comment: Jan already did it. I was too slow. I'm glad it helped though

Comment: Why so complicated if you just want everything but `msgid`? Either cut msgid or do `/msgid\s?(.*)/` ...

Comment: @m02ph3u5 It's because I am working on custom localization solution and there's specific format I must follow, also msgid can be within translation string as well.

Comment: Yeah and what's that format? We don't know what your requirements are. Currently the best answer would be `do substring(msg, 6)` ...

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Answer is already given and accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the construct `[]` always requires at least **one** character, which it does not find when the string is empty. An easy solution would be to make it optional (add `?`):

```
~msgid(?:\s*)(\"[^\"]?(?:\\.|[^\"])*\")~m
```

See [a demo here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vL9dZ4/1).

Comment: Thank you. This is more accurate since I need [^\"].

Comment: @NikolaR.: Glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can further use this more [efficient technique](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.482.1.45/1/) to reduce backtracking.

```
msgid\s*("(?:[^\\"]*\\.)*[^\\"]*")
```

(this will also match, if there is nothing inside the double quotes)

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jS7eI7/2)

---

Depending on how you use the pattern, it might be necessary to further escape backslashes eg PHP:

```
$re = '/msgid\s*("(?:[^\\\"]*\\\.)*[^\\\"]*")/';
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/519412)